# Can I grep for the number of same results of a grep result?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

This is the grep command I have:

```
grep 'Query failed' file.txt | grep -o '\bT\w*'
```

Search for string 'Query failed' and then it gives me the words starting with T.

Result is for example:

```
Test1
Test1
Test2
Test2
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test4
```

Is it possible to get a result like:

```
Test1 = 2
Test2 = 3
Test3 = 1
Test4 = 2
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

One option, extending your current pipeline, would be to use `uniq` to count the occurrences and `awk` to reformat the line:

```
your_commands | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " = " $1 }'
```

Note that `uniq` expects to receive sorted input, so you may need to pipe to `sort` beforehand.

Alternatively, you could do the whole thing in awk:

```
awk '/Query failed/ { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^T/) ++seen[$i] } 
    END { for (i in seen) print i " = " seen[i] }' file
```

On lines matching the pattern, loop through all the words and keep a count of any starting with "T". Once the file has been processed, loop through the array and print the results.

Note that associative arrays are unsorted in awk, so the order of the output may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe it to `sort` and `uniq -c` to count all the repetitions.

```
grep 'Query failed' file.txt | grep -o '\bT\w*' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output will be:

```
   2 Test1
   3 Test2
   1 Test3
   2 Test4
```

From your example, it looks like the original file is already sorted. If so, you can omit the `sort` step.

Comment: Thank you! Can I also sort after the number instead of the Test?

Comment: `uniq` requires its input to be sorted, so you have to sort before `uniq`.